# Loading Overlay Over Main Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a "Register Now" overlay on top of my main registration page. This is only to show if the user navigates to the first page of my site. By clicking on the "Register Now" button, the overlay is immediately hidden. However, I'm having trouble with the overlay showing up randomly throughout the site. How can I restrict the overlay to only showing if the user is at the Home page? I'm using codeigniter, but I'm trying to achieve this via javascript only. The home page url is formated www.xyz.com/register and subsequent pages in the site are www.xyz.com/register/2 and so on, with the number at the end of the url meaning page number.

```
<body>
<div id="v2Overlay">
  <button class="registerNow"></button>
</div>
<sitecontent></sitecontent>
</body>

<style>
    #v2Overlay
    {
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        position:absolute;
        z-index: 999;
    }
</style>
    <script>
        $(".registerNow").click(function()
        {
            console.log("clicked");
            $("#v2Overlay").hide();
            $("#wrapper").show();
        });
            $(function() {
                var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
                var href= window.location.href;

                //LOGIN PAGE = YES
                if (base_url === href)
                {
                    $("#wrapper").hide();
                    $("#v2Overlay").show();
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defaulting the #v2Overlay CSS class to display:none, and then only show it when you're on the home page.. If you're using CodeIgniter, it should pretty easy to determine when you are on the login page based on if you set that as the main view from your controller when there isn't an active session registered..